# AngularJS - ng-init directive nested into ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I need to create an array based in the following features:

Every time the ng-repeat directive list an object the init() function automatically sends these parameter to the controller in order to get an object.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="user in users" data-ng-init="init(user.id)">
```

In the other side, the init() function receive these parameter and then returns an object.

```
// Suppose I have 5 parameters in order to get 5 publications
$scope.init = function(id){
    $http.get("getPublicationByID/"+id)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
         // Here is the object that I need to create an array
         $scope.publication = data; }) 
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $log.error("Error!")})
}
```

My question is, how can I create an array based on all these objects?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ng-init on each ng-repeat element, you could easily loop through users object and call ajax for each user and collect all publications together.

For that you need to use `$q` API's `.when` & `.all` method to wait till all promises get resolved.

**Code**

```
getAllPublications function(){
    var promiseArray = [];
    $scope.publications = []
    angular.forEach($scope.users, function(user){
       promiseArray.push($q.when($http.get("getPublicationByID/"+user.id)));
    })
    $q.all(promiseArray).then(function(response){
       $scope.publications = response; //response is array of all publications
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have explained the same question in more detail. Can you give a hand? This is the question [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154332/angularjs-nested-ng-repeat-using-two-objects)